# The primary key not work

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

i am new in adroid. i have created a table like this:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "FAEXPED";
    public static final int version = 1;    
    public static String tableName = "LesOrdres";

    public static final String KEY_CodeClient = "CodeClient";
    public static final String KEY_CodeDest = "CodeDestinataire";
    public static final String KEY_NoOrdre = "NoOrdre";
    public static final String KEY_Ordre_1 = "Ordre_1"; 
    public static final String KEY_Ordre_2 = "Ordre_2"; 
    public static final String KEY_DateOrdre = "DateOrdre";
    public static final String KEY_GPSOrdre = "GPSOrdre";       

    private static final String TAG = "Create_The_DB";

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            tableName + "( "+ KEY_CodeClient + " VARCHAR, "+ KEY_CodeDest +"  VARCHAR," + KEY_NoOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_1 +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_2 +"  VARCHAR, "
                            + KEY_DateOrdre + " DATE, "+ KEY_GPSOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"     
             + " PRIMARY KEY("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+"))";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        //super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(context, DBName, null, version);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.w(TAG, TABLE_CREATE);   
      db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                 + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

and my SQLControll:

```
public long createItmes(Pers_Ordre ItmOrdre) {

      ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CodeClient, ItmOrdre.getLe_CodeClient());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CodeDest, ItmOrdre.getLe_CodeDest());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NoOrdre, ItmOrdre.getLe_NoOrdre());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Ordre_1, ItmOrdre.getLe_Ordre_1());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_Ordre_2, ItmOrdre.getLe_Ordre_2());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_DateOrdre, ItmOrdre.getLe_Date());
      initialValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_GPSOrdre, ItmOrdre.getLe_GPS());

      return database.insert(DBHelper.tableName, null, initialValues);
     }
```

and Main activity to insert the data via scan:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            if (scanContent != null)
            {
                String[] TempOrdre = scanContent.split("_");

                dbcon.open();
                Pers_Ordre oOrdre = new Pers_Ordre();
                oOrdre.setLe_CodeClient(TempOrdre[0]);
                oOrdre.setLe_CodeDest(TempOrdre[1]);
                oOrdre.setLe_NoOrdre(TempOrdre[2]);
                oOrdre.setLe_Ordre_1(TempOrdre[3]);
                oOrdre.setLe_Ordre_2(TempOrdre[4]); 
                oOrdre.setLe_Date(LedateFormat.format(Ledate));
                oOrdre.setLe_GPS(TempAddr);

                dbcon.createItmes(oOrdre);
                dbcon.close(); 
            }
            else
            {
                finish();
//              Intent GoToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//              startActivity(GoToMain);
            }


        }
        else{           
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

as you can see that i have 5 Primary keys.
Question:

1. i can insert the value null into KEY_GPSOrdre, it is strange because    as i know the primary key not allowed null value
2. i can insert the same key value (double), normaly it will rejected it.

i have edited like this:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            tableName + "( "+ KEY_CodeClient + " VARCHAR, "+ KEY_CodeDest +"  VARCHAR," + KEY_NoOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_1 +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_2 +"  VARCHAR, "
                            + KEY_DateOrdre + " DATE, "+ KEY_GPSOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"     
             + " PRIMARY KEY("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+")"
             + " UNIQUE     ("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+") ON CONFLICT REPLACE)";
```

but still i can create double.
my data is:

```
Code Client  NoORdre    Key1Ordre   DateOrdre             GPSOrdre
1406         2555       1           11/08/2014 16:30      NULL
1406         2555       1           11/08/2014 16:30      NULL
```

i edited again:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            tableName + "( "+ KEY_CodeClient + " VARCHAR, "+ KEY_CodeDest +"  VARCHAR," + KEY_NoOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_1 +"  VARCHAR,"+ KEY_Ordre_2 +"  VARCHAR, "
                            + KEY_DateOrdre + " DATE, "+ KEY_GPSOrdre +"  VARCHAR,"     
             + " PRIMARY KEY("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+")"
             + " UNIQUE     ("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+") ON CONFLICT REPLACE)";

    private static final String UNIQUE_INDEX = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_Ordre ON "+tableName+
                          "("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+")";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.w(TAG, TABLE_CREATE);   
      db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
      db.execSQL(UNIQUE_INDEX);
    }
```

but still not work, i still got double.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have five primary keys, you have a composite primary key consisting of five columns.

For inserting NULLs, consider the [following](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> Each row in a table with a primary key must have a unique combination of values in its primary key columns. For the purposes of determining the uniqueness of primary key values, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs.

For inserting the same values, it's the combination of all columns making up the composite key that matters.

If you want to restrict a column to unique values, use a `UNIQUE` constraint on it.

Comment: can you tell me how can i make unique for 5 columns ? the syntax ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to make unique? Each column in isolation?

Comment: may be something like this  + " UNIQUE("+KEY_CodeClient+","+ KEY_NoOrdre+","+KEY_Ordre_1+","+KEY_DateOrdre+","+KEY_GPSOrdre+")